# Find scale difference between OBJ and usdz

Tags: transforms, obj

I have imported an OBJ of a 3D scanned object and made modifications to the mesh.

After exporting, I realized that OBJ does not contain the real world size of the mesh.

I have the original OBJ as well as usdz of the scanned object. I believe usdz represents the real world size of the object but if I import it, I will have to make the mesh changes again.

I want to scale my mesh (the one originally imported from the OBJ).

How can I deduce the amount by which to scal so that I will arrive at its real world size?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.